# Is it safe to build a drop down table to a wooden wall?

Tags: wood, walls, table

I have a wooden wall (I just moved in, so I don't know which wood) 6cm thick.
I want to build an IKEA Norbo drop down table (https://www.ikea.com/de/de/p/norbo-wandklapptisch-birke-80091713/). The weight of the table is 8.33kg.

Is it safe to build this table to the wall? I'm worried the wall is not strong enough and it breaks. And if it is safe, which type of screws should I use? It will be used as a kitchen table, mainly for cutting ingredients.

Comment: Are you intending on purchasing that IKEA table and mounting it on your wall or building your own from scratch?

Comment: @MichaelKaras The intention is buying that specific IKEA table and mounting it on the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would follow the manufacturer's directions for mounting the drop down table to the wall. Also consider that the flat rail that is against the wall just under the table top area would be best if it could be screwed into the studs in the wall and not just through some thin wall board material.

This table at 79cm wide should be wide enough that the support board can span at least two studs in the wall. You may need to adjust the mount location in order to achieve that.

Comment: The wall looks that is was built to separate the bedroom from the kitchen. All the other walls are concrete walls, but this one is made out of wood. So you think if I screw it into the stud it would support the table's weight and the work I would do on top (mainly cutting ingredients)?

Comment: @OriolMiró - I had tried to already indicate in my answer that it is best to screw into the studs. If you do that with good quality wood screws and that you pre-drill the proper size pilot holes  it should be plenty strong. Even two screws into each stud should be sufficient,

Comment: sorry I made you type it again. Thank you for the answer!